# what is the meaning of double question mark and ; in sas code

Tags: sas

Could anyone explain following codes?

```
ASEX=put(sex, ?? Asex.);;
```

Why is there a `??` and why are there two semicolons (`;`) at the end?

Comment: I googled "[double question mark sas](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p19en16vskd2vhn1vwmxpxnglxxs.htm)" and "[double semi-colon sas](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Why-two-consecutive-semicolons-are-needed/td-p/29445)" and instantly got answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ? and ?? are modifiers on the informat that tell SAS not to signal an error when the value being read is not compatible with the informat being used.

> Format Modifiers for Error Reporting
>
> ?
>
> suppresses printing the invalid data note when SAS encounters invalid
> data values. See  How Invalid Data Is Handled
>
> ??
>
> suppresses printing the messages and the input lines when SAS
> encounters invalid data values. The automatic variable _ERROR_ is not
> set to 1 for the invalid observation.

The extra semicolon just creates an empty statement.